# How to stop button from getting scrunched?

Tags: android, button, textview, android-linearlayout

I'm having a problem with my buttons being pushed a bit whenever the number in my TextView goes into double, triple digits etc. How can I make it so the buttons stay the same size and don't get scrunched?

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"

    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="-"
        android:onClick="decrement"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"

        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:onClick="increment"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only give weight properties to middle `TextView` and set wrap_content to both `Button` :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:onClick="decrement"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:onClick="increment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```